# Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user with Capistrano v3.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm getting following error, while deploy in the production server

```
cap production rvm:check

cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@<server_name>: Authentication failed for user user@<server_name>

Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user user@<server_name>

Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
```

Here is my code in **config/deploy/production.rb**:

```
role :app, %w{<server_name>}
```

`server '<server_name>',
    user: 'user',
    roles: %w{app},
  ssh_options: {
    verbose: :debug,
    proxy: Net::SSH::Proxy::Command.new('ssh user@mygateway -W %h:%p')
  }`

I can't able to find out the issue while deploying. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I found solution for this issue and working good